# URL changed in sms sent by Twilio

Tags: url, twilio, sms, tinyurl

URL we send in message is like “tinyurl.com/abcceb8w” but when received by user in sms extra sign "@" is appended at end like “tinyurl.com/abcceb8w@” , which makes the URL invalid.

 Issue is occurring for Canadian numbers. Works fine for USA and other countries.

 What is possible reason for the issue and what is its fix?

Answer (score 1):

First, never use public URL shorteners in SMS messages, it will dramatically increase the chances of your message being blocked by carriers.

Second, open a ticket with Twilio support (via the Twilio Console, upper right hand side, under the `?`, Submit a Ticket), as the can investigate what happened.